# Which runs faster ... MIN or MAX in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

Which runs faster ... MIN or MAX in SQL Server?

This will help me optimize a query.

Thanks!

**Please vote to close this question.**

Comment: I honestly fail to see a circumstance where, even if one were faster than the other, it would help optimize a query.

Comment: @corsiKa It's the difference between inserting X and -X? ;-)

Comment: Why don't you try this yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am fairly sure that neither will be faster. You could easily measure this for yourself on your data.

Besides:

- They give different results. You can't just exchange one for the other.
- Even if one turns out to be slightly faster, this is a micro-optimization.

If you want to optimize your query then add appropriate indexes, and make sure your query is able to use the indexes efficiently. Check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Both have the same execution time. No Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

creating indexes is your solution here.